# IIS https website can't enter

Tags: https, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

Update 4/12:

I'm using Vigor 2910 (router) to connect to my server. I found out that I cloud view the website correctly by external ip from other PC. But everytime I try to login the browser redirects me to internal ip. Is there any settings I should know besides port forwarding 80 and 443 from external ip to internal ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix the problem.

My problem is, when I use another PC connected to different router trying to connect to the PHP site with external IP, it always redirect me to internal IP address.

For example:

1. Entering site https://140.XXX.XX.XXX
2. After clicking any objects on the site, then I was redirect to https://192.XXX.X.XXX

Cause I'm connected to the router that I didn't notice it not only affects my PC but also in PHP config.php. In config.php, the redirecting address is written in internal IP instead of external IP.

Just simply change the IP to external IP, then it works.